# Nullable value in a WindowsRT DatePicker (8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I can't seem to get anything working with a simple XAML project that has the DatePicker accepting a nullable value and therefore the Date/Month/Year boxes are showing this text as placeholder.

Can anyone help? I've found very little from other people on the web about this!

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datepicker does not accepts null values. Have a converter to check if the date passed is null,if yes hide the content.